# NoSQL with ColdFusion, Bean+Service+DAO & OOP or good old Array/Struct & Procedural?

Tags: mongodb, coldfusion, nosql

How do you architect the CF backend model w/ NoSQL that are simple, flexible, efficient and clean?

Since NoSQL doc has no fixed schema like SQL row, it doesn't really fit well with Objects which are rather static.  Therefore the typical Bean+DAO+Service OOP architecture doesn't seem to fit well.

I'm thinking of using plain old Struct's, but then I cannot add behavior onto it and it's going to make the whole project very procedural, which may not be a bad thing?

However, if I just use plain old struct, the DB implementations is leaked everywhere including the View layer...

Or... shall I translate the array's into CF's Query object for the View layer?

Comment? Idea? Suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: also asked here: http://groups.google.com/group/cfcdev/browse_thread/thread/4e9c95261beb7529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled with Proxy object (that has an embed 'instance' struct).  The DAO layer just use getMemento() & setMemento()

I also used an Iterator object for iterating through an array of results.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a couple applications in CF that use NoSQL datastores - one uses the Google App Engine datastore, and another with MongoDB.

In both cases, I made CFCs to act as my objects.  But, I used a homegrown object "framework" that uses onMissingMethod for accessors, and cfproperty with lots of custom metadata to define properties of the objects.

For instance, this is all I NEED to define for a model, unless it has custom business logic:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" persistentLayer="GAE" persistentClass="asana" extends="com.bespokelogic.framework.BaseModel">
    <cfproperty name="id" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true" required="true">
    <cfproperty name="deckSet" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true" default="basic">
    <cfproperty name="englishName" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
    <cfproperty name="traditionalName" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
    <cfproperty name="pronunciation" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
    <cfproperty name="anatomicalFocus" type="array" persistentDatatype="array" settable="true" gettable="true" default="#arrayNew(1)#">
    <cfproperty name="therapeuticFocus" type="array" persistentDatatype="array" settable="true" gettable="true" default="#arrayNew(1)#">
    <cfproperty name="benefits" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
    <cfproperty name="variations" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
    <cfproperty name="contraindications" type="array" persistentDatatype="array" settable="true" gettable="true" default="#arrayNew(1)#">
    <cfproperty name="skill" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
    <cfproperty name="instructions" type="string" persistentDatatype="string" settable="true" gettable="true">
</cfcomponent>
```

The CFCs all extend a base model which has validate, serialize, deserialize, and virtual getter/setter methods.

Then, I have a persistence layer that knows how to get and put objects from/into the datastore.

I would then write a service for each of the models which utilize the persistence layer.

The upshot is that the models know how to serialize their property data, and the persistencelayer knows how to put that into the datastore.

So, in a sense, its not an object-relational manager, but more of an object-document manager.

The framework's a lot more full featured in reality, as my design was that I take some models, and persist them in SQL, some in NoSQL, all in the same application - and I could swap out the underlying datastore with no recoding of the app.  It was a partial success.

In your case, if you're using a single datastore, you can skip all that complicated stuff.

You just need a base object which knows how to serialize and deserialize models, and you getter/setter stuff.  Decide how you want to store property data in the CFC.  I used a struct called "variables.instance._properties{}"

Then write a service for your model(s) that has "put" and "fetch" methods.  The "put" method, for instance, takes a model, calls the "serialize" method on it to turn it into JSON, then stuffs it into Mongo.  The "fetch" method gets the Mongo record, creates a new instance of the CFC, and passes the Mongo record to the deserialize method.

That was pretty rambling...

TL;DR:  "Objects in CF (such as they are) are not really all that static.  Use CFCs.  Use onMissingMethod to allow dynamic properties.  Store properties in a way that allows you to serialize and deserialize them into a format (usually JSON) that is easily digestible by your datastore.  Write a simple persistence layer that gets and puts documents to/from the datastore.  Write simple services which implement your persistence layer and take and return you dynamic models.

CF's pretty well suited for NoSQL in my opinion.

Comment: thx for your answer, but I'm wondering... if your all your entity does is serialize and deserialize, how is it better then just using a good old Struct?

Comment: Objects should represent the data IMO - but maybe Adobe will provide a way to serialize an object to a struct in the next release. See here: https://groups.google.com/group/cfmongodb/browse_thread/thread/5f14a9b89f30d51b

Comment: @Henry - because its a CFC, I can, if I need to do something beyond the built in validation in my framework, write custom getter and setter methods - this makes things more "static" as you say, but I could also, instead, write custom validator methods, and tweek the framework to allow the "validation" metadata property to reference a method.  I can have properties of the object that appear in the serlialization, but can't be set externally.  I can have properties of the object that do not appear in the serialization.  I get all the benefits of a CFC.

Comment: @Ciaran - that's basically what I did as well, but wrote it generically enough that the same objects and services can support a Mongo datastore, a BigTable datastore, or a SQL datastore (or any other datastore by writing a specific datastore implementation)